how to execute requests one by one in a useEffect
I have useEffect that executes the request when changing dependences (department and two dates field).
useEffect(() => {
    getFilteredRestReport({
      date_start: formatDatePatchPoint(date[0]),
      date_end: formatDatePatchPoint(date[1]),
      department,
    });
  }, [date, department])

When I make a request with an empty department, the request takes a long time to complete, and if during this request I make a request, for example, for some department, it will be executed first than without the department, but then when the request without departments is loaded, it will replace the data, although in the filter on the front, I have the last request department selected. And the question is how to stop an unnecessary request, or how to execute requests one by one?
I tried to do it with async/await
const request = async () => {
    await getFilteredRestReport({     
      date_start: formatDatePatchPoint(date[0]),
      date_end: formatDatePatchPoint(date[1]),
      department,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    request()
  }, [date, department]);


I'm not sure if it's allowed, but maybe you can call them as async functions? For example, have each in their own async function and await to run them so you know they're finished before continuing

you can wait a few seconds with setTimeout before to send the http request.

@schnondle, could you write an example?

@mmm, i think its degrades user experience

of course, you have to inform the user during the waiting time.

What does getFilteredRestReport do when it's called? Basically it sounds like you need to integrate an AbortController and abort any in-flight requests when making the next request. Please [edit] your post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Knowing it is an asyncThunk function, from the following documentation. This should work:
useEffect(() => {
  const reportPromise = getFilteredRestReport({
    date_start: formatDatePatchPoint(date[0]),
    date_end: formatDatePatchPoint(date[1]),
    department,
   });
  
  return () => {
    reportPromise.abort();
  }
}, [date, department])


getFilteredRestReport its createAsyncThunk function, and I write the response to redux state and then use this state in the component

Oh, when using a createAsyncThunk function you need a dispatch to call it, this is done with dispatch = useDispatch(), and then you have to dispatch your asyncthunk function dispatch(getFilteredRestReport({params})), if this still doesn't work I should have a solution for that too!

yes I know it, I use bindActionCreators from redux to use actions like prop functions.
